# ViewPager state persistent in fragment

Tags: android

I have a scenario where I am using bottomNavigation with 3 fragments to load in single Activity. In  fragment two  I have a pager with multiple fragments. I wanted to retain the state of fragment two once all respective fragments loaded with views in pager.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: The  activity level schema is done and created  fragment two pager with dynamic fragments as per requirements and  used same fragment with multiple instance by creating new object when pager adapter rendering list .When I am trying to change the main fragments view on bottomNavigation click ...there I am facing issue for state persistent.

Comment: Check your log. Put your log on these two fragment. Are they being initiated?

Comment: Yes these are initiated and also able to add multiple instance of single fragment with respective views only once I change my fragment from bottomNav it will not able to retain last loaded state.

Comment: If cant be able to retain what was the log reply

Comment: Hey after hectic things I think I have resolved issue..

Answer (score 0):

After hectic things I think I have resolved issue.. 
I have used Singleton design  pattern to handle this,

My parent Fragment is a singleton class which will hold fragment list that list will have a fragment to render UI.

Once user will click on bottomNavigation it will load same fragment instance as it already has a list of fragments so once I will insure that it has list I am rendering pager with same list and its same instance of fragment.

Code: To persiste

```
if(listOfFragments!=null&&listOfFragments.size>0)
    binding.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(notificationBinding.notificationTabsContainer);
    binding.tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    binding.notificationTabsContainer.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    binding.notificationTabsContainer.setOffscreenPageLimit(listOfFragments.size());
```